# Hidden "space" breaks PHP Object property name after retrieving SQL result

Tags: php, codeigniter, ascii, whitespace

I was having an issue where I could get an object back from a Codeigniter query, run `print_r($object)` and it would show:

```
stdClass Object ( [client_id] => 4105 [name] => William Hilliard ...
```

However, when I tried to print `$object->name`, nothing printed to the screen. Using Codeigniter's `result_array()` function to retrieve the result fixed the ability to print the value, but still did not explain why an Object property would not print to the screen. Even then, I wanted an object, not an array. Eventually, I went to the SQL I was running:

```
SELECT 
t.client_id as client_id
,CONCAT_WS(' ',t.first,t.last) as name
,t.foo as bar...
```

When I quoted `name` as `name` with tildes, the problem was fixed. This made me curious, so I downloaded BBEdit and looked at the line. In every other text editor, there was no space at the end of the line, but deleting and rewriting the line would fix the problem. BBEdit showed something different:

```
Δ  Δ  Δ  Δ  ,CONCAT_WS(' ',t.first,t.last)·as·name ¬
```

It clearly shows a space between `name` and `¬`. Copying and pasting this 
"whitespace" resulted in nothing pasting in text editors and web browsers. However, deleting the character and saving the file in BBEdit would fix the problem in PHP. Can anyone tell me what character this "phantom space" is and a possible way that a developer could have ended up with this garbage in their code?

Comment: You have pasted a normal space here. In your code it is some other character. Ask a developer why they inserted it there.

Comment: Use [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm), get character code, solve mystery.

Comment: That is why you should sterilize your submitted data first before putting it in the database.

Comment: @vsogrimen - you should sanitize data before putting it into the database, but this is not the reason why. the problem is coming from the file being executed by PHP. it has nothing to do with the database itself.